# How I can store object in JAXB?

Tags: java, jaxb

I have `pointbrush` class, this class contain object attribute `colorPoint` this attribute type is `Color`.I use `JAXB` for generation all my class but my question how can store Color attribute in `XML` with out generate class Color because `JAVA` have this class and i used this class, so I don't want generation other time.

In my schema:

```
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/ProjectDataBase"
<complexType name="PointBrush">
            <element name="ColorPoint" type="string" maxOccurs="1"
                minOccurs="1">
            </element>
            <element name="ColorPoint" type="tns:ColorPoint" maxOccurs="1"
                minOccurs="1">
            </element>
</complexType>
<complexType name="ColorPoint">
        <sequence>
            <element name="r" type="float" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1"></element>
            <element name="g" type="float" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1"></element>
            <element name="b" type="float" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1"></element>
            <element name="t" type="float" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1"></element>
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
</schema>
```

Java Code:

```
public class PointBrush   {
    @XmlElement(name = "ColorPoint")
    protected Color colorPoint;

    public Color getColorPoint() {
        return colorPoint;
    }
    public void setColorPoint(Color value) {
        this.colorPoint = value;
    }
}
public class BrushPointMr{
         public boolean Insert(PointBrush entity) {
            jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Project.class);
            Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            Project project = (Project) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
            PointBrush newBrush = objectFactory.createPointBrush();
            newBrush.setColorPoint(entity.getColorPoint());
            ////what can I do in java code for store object Color///////
         }
}
```

Comment: you don't need to generate class for Color. You just need to marshall newBrush to file. What's the problem?

Comment: you know Color class content a lot of attribute how i can said get just rgbt and but inside ColorPoint XML database

Comment: Did you generate PointBrush class from XML schema, or did you create it manually?

Comment: I generate PointBrush class and after that i delete ColorPoint class because i want use Color java.

Comment: Then default marshalling is not going to work.You would need to sub-class Msrshaller class and overwrite its 'marshall' method, which looks like a bigger task to me than using the standard approach.

Comment: can you give me example and that is the bitter way for do that and that is true for software engineering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Starting from an XML Schema

You can use an external binding file to configure XJC to do what you want.  In the example below the existing class `com.example.Foo` will be used for the complex type named `Foo`.

**binding.xml**

```
<jxb:bindings 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    version="2.1">

    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="yourSchema.xsd">
        <jxb:bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='ColorPoint']>
            <jxb:class ref="java.awt.Color"/>
        </jxb:bindings>
     </jxb:bindings>
 </jxb:bindings>
```

**XJC Call**

```
xjc -d outputDir -b binding.xml yourSchema.xsd
```

**Note**

You are going to manually need to add a package level `XmlAdapter` for the `Color` class to properly do the XML conversion.

### Handling a Problematic Class

When you have a class that JAXB can't convert by default you can use an `XmlAdapter` to convert it to one that can for the purpose of marshalling & unmarshalling.

Comment: please till me, what you mean in XJC and how i can used for Color class in my code.

Comment: @user3858035 - XJC is the XML Schema to Java Compiler.  It is used to generate a JAXB annotated model from an XML Schema.  You don't need to use it if you are starting from Java classes.  Are you starting from a schema or classes?

Comment: I starting by schema and after that generated class java